# Need advice on possible DS techniques for a problem

Tags: optimization

I am a former engineer, and a newbie data scientist, and am looking for advice on techniques to solve a particular problem for a personal project.

Suppose that a store is selling 2 items, A and B, which cost \$10 and \$20 each.

The goal is to set prices at any point in time to maximize overall sales and revenue for the store, and continue to offer both A and B without explicitly choosing one over the other i.e. the goal is not to explicitly select a winner. The goal is to both discover the best prices for sale per item, as well as optimize overall revenue.

What techniques could I use to achieve this? Can I formulate this as a Multi armed bandit? Can I use something simpler and more basic?

I'm relatively inexperienced in DS and will appreciate any comments, insights, and pointers to code samples to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: It depends on the data you have. Could you clarify what data is available? Is it a project for a real business to improve its sales, or is it a theoretical project to improve your knowledge in DS?

Comment: Hi Nicholas, thanks for responding. Right now I'm just looking to learn, but I may want to eventually use it to improve sales and revenue in a small clothing store that my parents own.

Comment: Ok Vee, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Discovering the best prices is based on sales prediction: the more the demand will be, the higher you can increase the price and vice versa.

But before making predictions through data science models, the first step is to analyze data with libraries like numpy, pandas, or seaborn. This will help you to understand general sales issues and take the first strategic decisions such as top & worst sales, trends, or detect some seasonality.

```
articles = pd.read_csv("file_path" / "articles.csv", dtype = {'article_id': str})
articles_2020 = articles.date_range("2019-01-01","2019-12-31")
best_sales_2020 = articles_2020.sort_values(["sales_count"], ascending=False).head(10)
```

Here you have clothing data from H&M with notebooks:

https://www.kaggle.com/code/negoto/h-m-sales-period-of-fashion-items-with-k-means/data

Then, you can use machine learning models to do accurate predictions. Random Forest (RF) is a good one to start with because it has good results with a few lines of code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
# Divide the data between units sold and influencing factors
X = articles.filter(["price","date","category","..."])*
Y = df["sales_count"]
# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state = 3)
# Set up and run the model
RFRegressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 10)
RFRegressor.fit(X_train, Y_train)
predictions = RFRegressor.predict(X_test)
error = Y_test - predictions
```

*Note: A good practice is to use day, month, and year separately instead of the full date in order to build rules easily with RF.

Source: https://towardsdatascience.com/predicting-e-commerce-sales-with-a-random-forest-regression-3f3c8783e49b

Comment: This is great, thanks for the detailed pointers. I'll take a look and let you know if I have any follow up questions. Have a great day.